# .NET Regex - How to find a term "surrounded" with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following lines:

```
MIAU,GD & LP
MIAU,GDMB & LP
```

I need to find the first line, with the matching rule: only if "GFD" and "LP" are present.

Currently I have the following regex:

```
new Regex(@"^(?=.*\bGD\b)(?=.*\bLP\b).*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

It's matching both lines.
How do I exclude the 2nd line from the match by ignoring preceding and following alphabet characters?

Comment: I don't see your regex matching either line.

Comment: Here, [it matches only the first one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fm)%5e(%3f%3d.*%5cbGFD%5cb)(%3f%3d.*%5cbLP%5cb).*%5cr%3f%24&i=A+%23GFD%2f+LP%0d%0aA+%22GFDSC+LP). If you are using `RegexOptions.Multiline`, it matches what it should (you can add `\r?` before `$` as `$` in multiline mode does not match a carriage return). Are you using a verbatim string literal (`@"...regex..."`)? Please  show the code.

Comment: @MattBurland I've updated the question, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @stribizhev yes, I'm using verbatim, I've updated the question

Comment: You need `RegexOptions.Multiline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `RegexOptions.Multiline` modifier and add `\r?` before `$`  as `$` in the multiline mode does not match a carriage return:

```
var text = "A #GFD/ LP\r\nA \"GFDSC LP ";
var pattern = @"^(?=.*\bGFD\b)(?=.*\bLP\b).*\r?$";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
         .Cast<Match>()
         .Select(p => p.Value)
         .ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s); // => A #GFD/ LP
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ZcksPR)